# (Python) Caesar Cipher not running

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I am an absolute beginner, so please forgive my stupidity when it comes to coding.
Ignore the french

```js
min='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
maj='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

def CoderCesar(txt,clef):
  crypt='' #string pour message crypté
  txt='' #string 
  for c in txt: #pour chaque caractere
    index=min.find(c) #regarder s'il appartient a l'alphabet en minuscule
    if index==False: #si ce n'est pas le cas
      index=maj.find(c) #vérifier s'il appartient alors a l'alphabet majuscule
      if index==False: #si le caractere n'est pas dans l'alphabet, 
        crypt+=c #le laisser et l'incrémenter tel quel dans le message crypté
      else: #si c'est une lettre majuscule
        cryptindex=index+clef #le nouvel indice est égal a l'indice de la lettre + plus la clé
        cryptindex%=len(maj) #revenir au début de la liste si l'indice dépasse la lettre 'z'
        crypt+=maj[cryptindex] # ajouter le caractere au message crypté
    else: #si c'est bien une lettre minuscule, faire exactement le meme proces qu'avant, en remplacant la liste majuscule par minuscule
      cryptindex=index+clef
      cryptindex%=len(min)
      crypt+=min[cryptindex]
  print("original:",txt)
  print("message crypt:",crypt)

CoderCesar(txt='Super! je sais coder ce message',clef=19)
```

Comment: You should also tell us what's wrong, not just that it's "not running".

Comment: well, i mean there's no error message that comes up after compiling the code, so i assume it must be a function calling problem. I'm a noob so I'm kinda lost, just thought maybe there was an easy and obvious solution

Comment: Surely the output was `original:`, `message crypt:`? No original message appearing should have given you a clue...

Answer (score 1):

You're re-initializing `txt` to an empty string at the start of your function, so the string you pass in (`"Super ! ..."`) is overwritten.

Remove the

```
txt = ""
```

line.

EDIT: Here's a simplified version of your code that does the trick.

```
min = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
maj = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"


def caesar_cipher(txt, key):
    crypt = ""
    for c in txt:  # for each character in source...
        for charlist in (min, maj):  # for each character list...
            index = charlist.find(c)
            if index == -1:
                continue  # Character c not found in this list
            crypt_index = (index + key) % len(charlist)
            crypt += charlist[crypt_index]
            break  # did encrypt character, break from loop and don't run below else
        else:  # Did not break from the loop, not a regular character
            crypt += c
    return crypt


message = "Super! je sais coder ce message"
clef = 25
crypt = caesar_cipher(txt=message, key=clef)
print(message)
print(crypt)
decrypt = caesar_cipher(txt=crypt, key=-clef)
print(decrypt)
```

Comment: hrmm, I did, but there must be a bigger underlying problem somewhere I can't seem to locate. Thanks for your help anyhow!

Comment: @will No problem... See my edit :)

Comment: wow! amazing, thank you so much @AKX!